# Docker overlays/containers are visible in Ubuntu file's manager after changing data-root of docker data directory

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I have recently moved docker data directory from `/var/lib/docker` to `/home/user/docker` as mentioned here https://www.guguweb.com/2019/02/07/how-to-move-docker-data-directory-to-another-location-on-ubuntu/
and all works fine, except I see all container's overlays/volumes in System file's manager as mounted drives.

[image]

They are visible until I stop docker/container. This is quite annoying with many containers running on.

Anybody faced this issue? Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone will face this problem in the future - just put it in `/home/docker`